# Using WS02 API Manager and WS02 IS server

Tags: rest, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have a basic question in using WSo2 API manager and WSo2 IS server.

I have a requirement , where I need to Authenticate/Authorize any requests coming to my rest services. When I read documentation on WSo2 website I see that we can achieve this using WSo2 ESB + WSo2 IS server.

But we don't want to use ESB rather than use a Lightweight component like WSo2 API manager + Ws02 IS server to fulfill the

I have gone through this documentation  and trying to setup WSO2 as the key manager

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.0.0+with+API+Manager+1.9.0

My question is I am going in the right direction ?

Will API manager alone will be sufficient for authentication/authorization

Answer (score 0):

Yes [above link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.0.0+with+API+Manager+1.9.0) will guide you to how to configure the Identity server with API Manager.
API manager will be sufficient for the basic authentication/authorization.but if you want advance options need to configure with the identity Server.([The Identity Server and the solution it provides](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Introducing+the+Identity+Server))